# Live Chat for my Xamarin.Forms App

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, chat, messenger

I'm developing a Xamarin.Forms app (for iOS and Android) and inside the app I need to introduce a live chat for users interaction. Will only be one-on-one chats, not groups. Just like Airbnb or so many social networks out there.

Is there any free option for what I need? I was thinking on an API based chat, but I don't know which service do I need to grab for my needs.

I would appreciate your suggestions since I don't have any information about this.

Thanks in advance,

Fernando.

Comment: Check the Telegram API, I think it suits just about every need for basic chatting

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at that.

Comment: You can do it yourself with SignalR. It´s relatively easy